# Can we use std::any_of for checking a value in a range?

Tags: c++

`std::any_of` and similar use a predicate to check the given range, but in a lot of cases, all I want is to check for a value.

So I want something like `std::ranges::any_of(my_string, id('j'));` to check whether the letter 'j' is in the string.

What is an easy implementation for `id()` for most types? Does the standard library already have this?

By the way, I know that there is already `std::ranges::contains` in C++23, I'm just wondering for a possible `id()` implementation.

I already have this:

```
template<std::equality_comparable T>
std::function<bool(T)> id(const T& i) { return [&i](const T& j) { return i == j; }; }
```

This works with

```
auto a2 = std::to_array<std::string>({ "hallo", "wereld", "!!!"});
std::cout << std::boolalpha << rng::any_of(a2, id(std::string("!!!"))) << "\n";
```

I'm just wondering if there is something better or already in the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`contains` is implemented in terms of `find`:

```cpp
std::ranges::find(my_string, 'j') != std::ranges::end(my_string);
```

Which doesn't need any helper functions.

---

The very best fully-featured implementation for `id` would look like:

```cpp
constexpr auto id(const auto& i) noexcept {
    return [&i](const auto& j) noexcept(noexcept(bool(i==j))) -> bool {
        return i == j;
    };
}
```

Which can reasonably be shortened to:

```cpp
constexpr auto id(const auto& i) { return [&](const auto& j) { return i == j; } }
```

Which also supports heterogeneous comparison better (e.g., `id(nullptr)` will work on an array of `T*` pointers)

Comment: I usually prefer lambda over bind, but in this case, the bind solution is clearer. It doesn't work for checking std::string in std::array though (VisualStudio, g++).

Comment: @stefaanv It seems that bind_front does not unwrap reference_wrappers, and `std::ref("!!!") == std::string{"hallo"}` doesn't compile (neither does `std::string s; std::ref(s) == s`, so a lambda works better.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I feel I should be able to upvote once more, because even though the bind solution wasn't perfect in this situation, it seems like something to consider when needed.

Comment: @stefaanv _"I feel I should be able to upvote once more"_ - Since you asked the question, you have the option to give the ultimate upvote: Accepting the answer.